# Sub Category listing according to category in drop down

Tags: javascript, php

I'm stuck here.

I want to display particular sub categories when a particular category is selected from the category drop down.

For instance, suppose we have categories :-

**Cate1
Cate2**

Then under Cate1, we have :-
*Sub1
Sub2*

and under Cate2, we have
*Sub3
Sub4*

Then how would the sub category change values according to the categories?I guess some js or php ?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what do you want, if you have simple and short list, use HTML ,  and

http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/optgroup/

If not, then yes, you must use JavaSript to build new select depending on main category value

Comment: Thankyou @Alvar FinSoft Soome
I'm a newbie in javascript, could you possibly guide me to a tutorial for this ?